# libcurl.so.4: no version information available (required by curl)

Tags: curl, installation, libcurl

```
$ ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/linuxbrew/go/install)"
curl: /software/ParticleRuntime/v84/bin/glnxa64/libcurl.so.4: no version information available (required by curl)
curl: (48) An unknown option was passed in to libcurl
```

Trying to install linuxbrew but this error keeps on coming up.

Using curl -V:
curl 7.35.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.21.6

It seems my curl and  libcurl are two different versions? But searching around I haven't found a method yet to fix this problem.

Can anyone help?

Thanks